# redirect to a different url after current url action php slim

Tags: php, routes, twig, slim

I'm developing a Slim application with twig engine for employees and would like to redirect the admin after adding a new user to the system to a page that will show the just added user. Now the problem is not getting the just added user but the redirection I'm doing it this way

```
//first render the page to add
$app->get('/api/employee/create', function () use ($app){
    $app->render('add.html.twig');
    $employee = R::findLast('employee', 'mobilenumber=?', array('mobilenumber'));
    header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
})->name('add');
```

in the add.html.twig I have a form that collects the data and set the action to another route that does the recording into the database.

If I happen to add the following into the above app section

```
$app->redirect('/home');
```

then visit /api/employee/create the /home route gets shown first and it assumes the rest what would be the best way to show the add.html.twig template first then after the form submission return me to /home or any other route I set. Thanks

Comment: You need to have the redirect in the route where you SAVE the data to database. Not in the route where you show the form.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
$app->get('/api/employee/create', function () use ($app){
    $app->render('add.html.twig');
});

$app->post('/api/employee/create', function () use ($app){
    $data1ToSave = $app->request()->post("data1_to_save");
    $data2ToSave = $app->request()->post("data2_to_save");

    // save datas

    $app->redirect('/home');
});
```